# How can i fetch all folders and outputs from the json object using lodesh

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

My object are like

```
        const items = {
               "items":[
        {
                             "folderId":2,
                             "folderName":"crt",
                             "folders":[
                                {
                                   "folderId":21,
                                   "folderName":"adam"
                                },
                                {
                                   "folderId":22,
                                   "folderName":"sdtm"
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "folderId":3,
                             "folderName":"derived_data"
                          },
                          {
                             "folderId":4,
                             "folderName":"ext_imp",
                             "folders":[
                                {
                                   "folderId":41,
                                   "folderName":"ext_impData",
                                   "folders":[
                                      {
                                         "folderId":411,
                                         "folderName":"tryData",
                                         "folders":[
                                            {
                                               "folderId":4111,
                                               "folderName":"PPT"
                                            }
                                         ],
                                         "outputs":[
                                            {
                                               "fielObjId":41111,
                                               "uid":"o1.sas7bdat",
                                               "isHidden":"N"
                                            }
                                          ]
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "folderId":5,
                             "folderName":"pgm",
                             "folders":[
                                {
                                   "folderId":51,
                                   "folderName":"data",
                                   "folders":[
                                      {
                                         "folderId":5111,
                                         "folderName":"demoData 1"
                                      }
                                   ],
                                   "outputs":[
                                      {
                                         "fielObjId":511,
                                         "uid":"o1.sas7bdat",
                                         "isHidden":"N"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                },
                                {
                                   "folderId":52,
                                   "folderName":"eff"
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "folderId":6,
                             "folderName":"pk_analysis"
                          },
                      {
                         "folderId":7,
                         "folderName":"reports",
                         "folders":[
                            {
                               "folderId":71,
                               "folderName":"eff"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "folderId":8,
                         "folderName":"util",
                         "folders":[
                            {
                               "folderId":81,
                               "folderName":"d_adtst_macro"
                            },
                            {
                               "folderId":86,
                               "folderName":"metadata",
                               "outputs":[
                                  {
                                     "fielObjId":81111,
                                     "uid":"o8.sas7bdat",
                                     "isHidden":"N"
                                  }
                               ]
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                  }
```

While looping I am storing data in different array, which contains only folders and array.

```
lodash.map(importList.items, (item) => {
           const { folders, folderName } = item;
           const folderPath = `${folderName}/`;
           if (folders && folders.length > 0) {
             this.getSelectedOutput(item, folderPath);
           }
         });
         const uniqList = selectedItemlist.length > 0 ? lodash.uniqBy(selectedItemlist, 'folderPath') : [];

     getSelectedOutput(data, path) {
         let obj = {};
         const { folders, folderName, outputs } = data;
         const folderPath = path.includes(folderName) ? path : `${path}${folderName}/`;

         if (outputs && outputs.length > 0) {
           const outputList = outputs.filter(item => item.isHidden === 'N');
           const selectedOutput = lodash.map(outputList, item =>

 lodash.extend({ isServerData: true }, item));
               obj = {
                 folderPath,
                 selectedOutput
               };
               selectedItemlist.push(obj);
             }
             lodash.map(folders, (folder) => {
               this.getSelectedOutput(folder, folderPath);
             });
           }
```

How can I create a new array which contains folders and outputs only?

Comment: how the expected output will look like

Comment: {
  "items": [
    {
        "folderPath": "pgm/data/",
        "selectedOutput": [
           {
              "fielObjId": 511,
              "uid": "o1.sas7bdat",
              "isHidden": "N"
        
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "folderPath": "util/metaData/",
        "selectedOutput": [
           {
              "fielObjId": 521,
              "uid": "PP1.sas",
              "isHidden": "N"
            }
        ]
      }
  ]
}

currently it's look like this